# Randomly Prefab Object on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

That is my first time here ;)

I have this SpawnController:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class SpawnController : MonoBehaviour {

        public float maxWidth;
        public float minWidth;

        public float rateSpawn;
        private float currentRateSpawn;

        public GameObject tubePrefab;

        public int maxSpawnTubes;

        public List<GameObject> tubes;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

            for (int i = 0; i < maxSpawnTubes; i++) {
                GameObject tempTube = Instantiate (tubePrefab) as GameObject;
                tubes.Add (tempTube);
                tempTube.SetActive (false);

            }

            currentRateSpawn = rateSpawn;

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

            currentRateSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
            if (currentRateSpawn > rateSpawn) {
                currentRateSpawn = 0;
                Spawn ();
            }
        }

        private void Spawn() {

            float randWitdh = Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth);
            GameObject tempTube = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxSpawnTubes; i++) {
                if (tubes [i].activeSelf == false) {
                    tempTube = tubes [i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (tempTube != null)
                tempTube.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, randWitdh, transform.position.z);
            tempTube.SetActive (true);
            }
    }
```

I want to spawn a prefab (randomly)  Tubes on X AXIS - 9.5 at 10.9... But when I play, the prefab spawns (ramdomly) on Y AXIS -9.5 at 10.90... what is wrong at my code?

Comment: Question solved!!  ...(transform.position.x, randWitdh, transform.position.z)...  Look, X, Y(set as random or seteable at inspector), Z i change to; (randWitdh, transform.position.x, transform.position.z); X (set as random or seteable at inspector), Y,Z now works perfect. i can set range at inspect for min and max witdh spawn at  X AXIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempTube.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, randWitdh, transform.position.z);`

I'd guess that your `randWitdh` is on the wrong axis.

It should be:

`tempTube.transform.position = new Vector3 (randWitdh, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

Comment: I make only a litle change: transform.position.Y to transform.position.X Now my my prefab spawn at X AXIS i set -9.5 ~10 (inspector) WORKS PRETTY GOOD now Thank!!!!

Answer (score 1):

well, i dont really understand what you mean, but the random part indeed IS on the y axis, not x ...

```
tempTube.transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, randWitdh, transform.position.z);
```

so maybe if you use randWidth as the first argument (the x coord) this is what you intend?

sry if this isnt what you mean at all, it kinda sounds too trivial ...

Comment: Dont work....  its possible make that SpawnController run around X AXIS -9.5 at 10.9? If yes that solve all my problem =]